# PHP / Files "type" not working when uploaded from windows

Tags: php

this works well on Mac (any browser) but when I try from windows (any browser) it gives the error. It looks like the "type" is not passed in windows. Any experience with this?

```
if(!preg_match('/(text\/csv|text\/plain)/', $_FILES['file']['type'])){ 
print "Error: File must be text/plain or text/csv."; 
exit; }
```

Comment: Post the result of `var_dump($_FILES['file'])` so we can see what it contains.

Comment: application/vnd.ms-excel

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
$type = $_FILES["file"]['type'];
if ($type == "text/csv" || $type == "application/vnd.ms-excel") {
echo "That's the file you need!";
} else { 
echo "Sorry, wrong type of file!";
}
```